# Php date issue algorithm

Tags: php, date

This is my code:

```
$current_day = strtotime(date("2015-04-20"));
for ($i=1; $i<= 5; $i ++){
   $choice_date = $get_choice_date->choice_date; // here i get dynamically the dates - y-m-d format
  if ( $current_day < strtotime($choice_date) ){ 
    if (strtotime(date("H:i:s")) < strtotime("17:00:00")){
         echo $i."-test";
    }
  }
}
```

Suppose that the current day is 2015-04-20. For instance:
if it is 2015-04-20(monday) and the time is passed by 17:00:00 then don't display `$i."-test";` - tuesday, but display the rest of the days; else if the time is before 17:00:00 then display tuesday and the rest of them. How can I do that?

Comment: Am I make myself clear, please ask me if you don't understand. thx :)

Comment: are you asking what should be in `$get_choice_date->choice_date` variable? BTW, how is it dynamically generated, it should be function or some array to which you pass `$i` variable?

Comment: I don't post it all of the code. I posted where is my problem, assume that the $choice_date will have the  values 2015-04-20, 2015-04-21, 2015-04-22, 2015-04-23 and 2015-04-24. Please help me with this

Comment: So it works as you described, where is the problem? You mean what should be echoed instead of `$i."-test"`?

Comment: if today is 2015-04-20 and  it is after 17:00 it don't displays the $i

Answer (score 1):

Think you want code similar to the following, if I understood your question correctly.

```
//$now = time();
$now = strtotime("2015-04-20 16:00:00");
$current_day = date("N", $now);
$current_hour = date("H", $now);
//$choice_date = strtotime($choice_date = $get_choice_date->choice_date);
$choice_date = strtotime("2015-04-28 18:00:00"); // an example date in future. Delete this line and uncomment the above.

$days = array("sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday");

if ($now < $choice_date) {
    $day_index = date("w", $now) + 1;
    if ($current_hour >= 17){
        $day_index++;
    }
    for ($i=$day_index; $i<= 5; $i ++){
        echo $days[$i] . $i."-test<br/>";
    }
}
```

The above gives the following output when the `$now` time is before 17:00,

```
tuesday2-test
wednesday3-test
thursday4-test
friday5-test
```

and the same output without Tuesday if it is after 17:00

If I have misunderstood, comment below to clarify.

Comment: I get the format from mysql, which is y-m-d I don't want to change it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another condition in case it is Monday after 17:00:

(`(strtotime(date("H:i:s")) >= strtotime("17:00:00") && $current_day == strtotime($choice_date)` )

and change `<` to `<=` in comparison to `$choice_date` to let Monday in:

```
$current_day = strtotime(date("2015-04-20"));
for ($i=1; $i<= 5; $i ++){
   $choice_date = $get_choice_date->choice_date; // here i get dynamically the dates - y-m-d format
   if ($current_day <= strtotime($choice_date) ){ 
     if ((strtotime(date("H:i:s")) < strtotime("17:00:00")) || (strtotime(date("H:i:s")) >= strtotime("17:00:00") && $current_day == strtotime($choice_date))){
      echo $i."-test";

    }
  }
}
```